# Foci Product of Distances Ellipse

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

> Show that the product of the distances from the foci to the tangent at any point of an ellipse is $b^2$ where $b$ is the semi-minor axis.

My process of proof so far:

Let $F(c, 0)$ and $F'(-c, 0)$ be 2 points that lie on the x-axis of the plane and $P(x_0, y_0)$ be the point that lies on the tangent to the ellipse. I simply started by simplifying the equation $$\sqrt{(x+c)^2+y^2}\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2}$$

However, this got me to a dead end. Plus, I feel as if there's some property about the tangent of an ellipse that I'm not using. If anyone could **guide** (not answer) me towards the answer, that would be extremely beneficial to my sanity (and knowledge, of course).

Thanks again.

Comment: As stated, the statement is (obviously) false: "any point of any tangent" can be arbitrarily-far from the ellipse, so the product of distances to such points is non-constant (and is, indeed, unbounded). You probably mean to write "the product of the distances from the foci **to the tangent at any point of an ellipse** is $b^2$ [...]". (I suppose you could mean something else, but at least this statement happens to be true.)

Comment: By the way: If the proper statement is as I suggested in my previous comment, then this question is a duplicate of ["Ellipse Focal Proof"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1073870/409).

Comment: That's what I think the question was trying to ask. I got this problem out of a book, so I was quite confused when the answer wasn't $b^2$.

Comment: Okay. Then I'm going to vote to close this question as a duplicate of the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Hint

WLOG the equation of the ellipse be $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1$

where $b^2=a^2(1-e^2)$

The coordinates of the foci are $(\pm ae,0)$

What is the equation of tangent at $P(a\cos t,b\sin t)$

What are the perpendicular distances of the foci from the tangent?