# How to find a family of tangents to a parametrized curve

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose I am given the curve $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{p^2}+\frac{y^2}{q^2}=1$. I want to write down explicitly an equation that parametrizes all tangent lines to this ellipse. In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1073870/for-an-ellipse-with-minor-radius-b-show-that-the-product-of-distances-from-th?noredirect=1&lq=1), the answers freely use the fact that the equation of any tangent line at a point $(x_0,y_0)$ of the ellipse can be written as $$\frac{x}{p^2}x_0+\frac{y}{q^2}y_0=1\space\text{or}\space\frac{x}{p^2}\left(p\cos(t)\right)+\frac{y}{q^2}q\sin(t)=1$$

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $(x_0,y_0)$ is a point of the ellipse with $y_0\ne 0.$ Deriving with respect to $x$ in $$\frac{x^2}{p^2}+\frac{y^2}{q^2}=1$$ we get

$$\frac{x}{p^2}+\frac{yy'}{q^2}=0$$ from where

$$y'=-\frac{q^2x}{yp^2}.$$ The equation of the tangent line is

$$y-y_0=y'(x_0)(x-x_0).$$ That is,

$$y-y_0=-\frac{q^2x_0}{y_0p^2}(x-x_0).$$ In other words

$$\frac{x}{p^2}x_0+\frac{y}{q^2}y_0=1.$$

If $y_0=0$ you can proceed in a similar way taking derivatives with respect to $y.$

Comment: Thank you very much! I’m working through Pressley’s book and some of his approaches to some of the exercises seem to be more difficult that need be - this is much simpler! Thanks!